# Python 3.6 rounding to 0.0

Tags: python

I am having a problem.I have the following code:

```
import json
import math


class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name="", last_name="", age=0, height=0, weight=0):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.bmi = self.__bmi()

    def __bmi(self):
        a = (self.weight / math.exp(self.height)) * 703
        print(a)
        b = round(a, 1)
        return b

    def print_json(self):
        print(json.dumps(self.__dict__))


Jane = Person(first_name="Jane", last_name="Doe", age=35, height=72, weight=130)

Jane.print_json()
```

By executing the above code I get output:

```
4.916952131643318e-27
{"height": 72, "weight": 130, "age": 35, "bmi": 0, "last_name": "Doe", "first_name": "Jane"}
```

It keeps rounding `4.916952131643318e-27` to `0.0`. I'm trying to round to `4.9`.

Comment: Why would you want to round 0.000000000000000000000000004916952131643318 to 4.9?

Comment: 4.9e-27 is a very small number, rounding to 1 digit *is* 0. Also, your BMI calculation looks off anyway. math.exp gives `e` to the `x` power. I believe you want `(self.weight / (self.height**2)) * 703`.

Comment: Thank you both, Mark and @17slim for your replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrote this as a comment, figured I may as well turn it into an answer.

`4.9e-27` is a very small number (0.0000000000000000000000000049), so rounding to 1 digit is 0. Also, your BMI calculation looks way off anyway. `math.exp(x)` gives `e` to the `x` power. I believe you want `(self.weight / (self.height**2)) * 703`.

Comment: I knew I had to be doing something wrong. This works. I've been out of school for 17 years. haha. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The number you are looking at is actually in scientific notation. Note the "e-27" -- that means it's actually 4.9 * 10^-27, or 4.9 divided by a 1 with 27 0s after it.  This obviously is very, very close to zero.

Comment: I mean `round(4.916952131643318e-27 * 1e27, 1)` would do what the OP wants I guess...

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. See my comment on the accepted answer. :)